# Query to get member count for group together with total points for each group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My simplified schema is:

- Participants (`Id`, `Email`)
- Teams (`Id`, `Name`)
- TeamMembers many-to-many mapping for Teams--Participants (`TeamId`, `ParticipantId`)
- Responses (`Id`, `ParticipantId`)
- ReponseDetails (`Id`, `ResponseId`, `Points`, `BonusPoints`)

For each Team that has at least 2 members I want to get TeamId, Total Member Count and Total Team Points. Total Team Points is sum of BonusPoints and Points from ResponseDetails from all team members. Note that Participant can be member of more than one team.

So far I have this query:

```
select 
    tm.[TeamId], 
    count(tm.[ParticipantId]) as 'TotalMemberCount', 
    sum(rd.[Points] + rd.[BonusPoints]) as 'TotalTeamPoints'
from 
    [TeamMembers] tm 
left outer join 
    [Responses] r on r.[ParticipantId] = tm.[ParticipantId] 
left outer join 
    [ResponseDetails] rd on r.[Id] = rd.[ResponseId]
where 
    tm.[TeamId] in (select [TeamId] from [TeamMembers] 
                    group by [TeamId] having count([ParticipantId]) > 1)
group by 
    tm.[TeamId]
```

It returns correct `TeamId` and `TotalTeamPoints` but incorrect `TotalMemberCount` (much higher). I have a feeling that I am missing something simple like grouping somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the left outer joins are causing some duplicates that are being counted in the "count(tm.[ParticipantId])". Try "count(distinct tm.[ParticipantId])".